# can someone tell me what is tmpl_context object in pylons

Tags: pylons

I could not find any document talking about **tmpl_context** object in pylons. Could someone teaches me about it or show me a document. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this part of the Pylons book: http://pylonsbook.com/en/1.1/exploring-pylons.html#context-object